# A question concerning complex conjugates of constants

Tags: complex-analysis

If $τ : \Bbb C → \Bbb C$ is given by $τ (z) = e^{iθ} \bar z + a$ then $τ^{−1}(z) = e^{−iθ} \overline {(z − a)}$ for some fixed $a ∈ \Bbb C$.

I know that I need to show that $τ τ^{−1} (z) = τ^{−1} τ (z) = z$ but I'm having trouble with the conjugates.

So far I have that $ τ τ^{−1} (z) = e^{iθ} \overline {(e^{−iθ} \overline {(z − a)})} + a$.

For $τ^{−1} τ (z) =  e^{-iθ} \overline{(e^{iθ} \bar z + a - a)} $.

Mainly, I am not sure how what to do with the conjugates of $e^{iθ}$, $e^{-iθ}$, and $a$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. Conjugation distributes over sums and products, so $\overline{a+b}=\overline{a}+\overline{b}$ and $\overline{ab}=\overline{a}\cdot\overline{b}$
2. If $\theta$ is real, then $$\overline{e^{i\theta}}=\overline{\cos\theta + i\sin\theta}=\cos\theta -i\sin\theta
   =e^{-i\theta}$$

Answer (score 1):

For real $\theta$, the complex conjugate of $e^{i\theta}$ is $e^{-i\theta}$ and the complex conjugate of $e^{-i\theta}$ is $e^{i\theta}$.

If a is real, then $\overline{a}= a$.